# Is there any neglible impact on USB read/write speeds using MBR/NTFS vs. GPT/HFS+ in OSX?

Tags: macos, hardware, usb

I have a 3 TB External Hard-drive, however, it was previously used with a Windows desktop and uses an MBR partition table and the single partition is using NTFS. As a result, I've been using various software solutions to mount the disk on OS X.

The full context of the question is this: If I were to purchase a second external hard drive, reformatted using GUID partition table and HFS+, would I see better performance in OS X reading from the disk?

It is typically used for media playback, so it is read-intensive and I was simply not seeing this performance issue on my Windows workstation or the Linux server this device was previously attached to.

Comment: Limits on size and GPT are not related to USB speed. Your question appears to be about NTFS vs HFS+ speed and not USB speed. Could you make the question and title correspond

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my title to better correspond to the full context of the question: Whether or not filesystem and partition table types would impact USB transfer on an OS X system.

Comment: Honestly, access patterns are what determine speed and they're largely task-dependant. Your best bet here would be to format one way, measure using something like [Black Magic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12), format the other way and measure again.

Comment: Thank you @IanC. That'll be something I need to look into when migrate the data to a larger disk soon; I'll try it using the new format and see what happens.